# VC dimension of Voronoi cells in R^d?

Tags: cg.comp-geom, machine-learning, lg.learning, convex-geometry, high-dimensional-geometry

Suppose I have $k$ points in $\mathbb{R}^d$. These induce a Voronoi diagram. If I assign to each of the $k$ points a $\pm$ label, these induce a binary function on $\mathbb{R}^d$. Question: what is the VC-dimension of all such possible binary functions induced by some $k$ points and some labeling of these points?

Comment: I see that a bound of $O(dk^2\log k)$ is given in [Theorem 1](http://noodle.cs.huji.ac.il/site/labs/learning/Papers/NNk_with_theory.ps.pdf).  Is that the best known?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check Theorem 21.5, Section 21 in the book "A probabilistic Theory of Pattern Recognition (1996)" from Devroye, Gyorfi, and Lugosi. I think the following upper bound is valid: VC $\leq$ $k + (d+1)k^2\log k$.

Comment: What is $n$ here?

Comment: Modulo the mystery $n$, this appears to be the same order of magnitude as I cited above.